# toPixels(): Project Longitudes & Latitudes to pixels of a custom view

Tags: android

I'm still facing a difficulty to project a list of geological positions to pixels. I have a custom view (derived from SurvaceView) for simply painting the coordinates.

My code:

```
x = (int) sView.getHeight() * ( (pos.getLat() - minLat) / (maxLat - minLat)) + margin;
...
myPoints.add(new Point(x,y));

onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  for (Point p : myPoints) {
    canvas.drawPoint(p.x, p.y, myPaint);
  }
```

.... doesn't fit the entire view. I am becoming desperate. Do you have a idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you want.

But if I understand you correctly, you want to plot a set of GPS-coordinates to a bitmap, and you want the resulting plot to fit the size of the bitmap.

If so, I suggest going for the following strategy:

1. Find the minimum and maximum latitudes and longitudes, MinLon, MaxLon, MinLat and MaxLat.
2. Subtract the minimum values from all the points (rebasing the data set to (0,0)).
3. Find the horizontal scale factor: ScaleX := (MyBitmap.Width) / (MaxLat - MinLat)
4. Find the vertical scale factor: ScaleY := (MyBitmap.Height) / (MaxLon - MinLon)
5. Loop through all the points in your dataset, and apply the lowest scale factor of ScaleX and ScaleY.

You will then have a set of points with coordinates that can  be plotted to your bitmap.

It will not be a cartographically correct projection, but it'll probably serve a starting point, at least.

Comment: Well, so I am on the right way with: (int) sView.getHeight() * ( (pos.getLat() - minLat) / (maxLat - minLat)) which is exactly the same - in this case - to transform the lat, right?

Comment: It seems similar, yes. Except I'd expect it to be (pos.getLat() - minLat) * ((int) sView.getHeight() / (maxLat - minLat)). In other words switching the first two factors.

Comment: I found a small bug in my code. Your approach is clear and absolutely acceptable :)